# Unfortunately Stops when click on Spinner Android

Tags: android, custom-controls, spinner

I have created a custom Spinner in my Android application.

When i click on my custom spinner my application gets stop Unfortunately.
Here i had put my error Log and Custom Adapter Code.
Here *Custom_Spinner_info* is my class where i stored my Custom_Spinner Row data.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom_Spinner_info> {

     private Activity context;
     ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> data = null;
     Custom_Spinner_info csi;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Activity context, int resource,ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> data) {
        super(context, resource,data);
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View convertView,ViewGroup vg)
    {
        return super.getView(pos, convertView, vg);

    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int pos,View convertView,ViewGroup vg)
    {
        View view=convertView;
        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, vg, false);
        }
        csi= data.get(pos);
        if(csi!=null)
        {
            TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(csi.getName());
        }
        return view;

}

public ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> populateList() { ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> mySpinner = new ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info>(); mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("USA", 308745538)); // Image stored in /drawable mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Sweden", 9482855)); mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Canada", 34018000)); return mySpinner; }
```

[image]

More details.

```
ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> mySpinner=populateList();

 public ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> populateList() { 

    ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> mySpinner = new ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info>();
    mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("USA", 308745538)); // Image stored in /drawable 
    mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Sweden", 9482855));
    mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Canada", 34018000)); 

   return mySpinner; 
}

 MyCustomAdapter adapter= new MyCustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mySpinner); 
 spi.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my declaration of spinner in xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />
```

**link to full code**

http://pastebin.com/3PP0dFv7

Comment: also post u r activity.

Comment: what is line 44 in the adapter ?

Comment: @Raghunandan View view=convertView;

Comment: @JigarShekh view is null. post the code where you invoke your custom adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan  ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> mySpinner=populateList();

Comment: @Raghunandan public ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> populateList()
    {
        ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info> mySpinner = new ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info>();
        mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("USA", 308745538)); // Image stored in /drawable
        mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Sweden", 9482855));
        mySpinner.add(new Custom_Spinner_info("Canada", 34018000));
        return mySpinner;
    }

Comment: @Raghunandan MyCustomAdapter adapter= new MyCustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mySpinner);
spi.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @JigarShekh please update your question

Comment: @JigarShekh pls edit your post and post the same

Comment: please post how you declare your spinner and where you declare it ?

Comment: your declaration of spinner in code

Comment: @Amrola Spinner spi=(spinner) findViewbyId(R.id.spinner1);

Comment: what i need you to post is your whole on create to see how you do all of these things togther

Comment: @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ArrayList<Custom_Spinner_info>  mySpinner=populateList();
spi=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

MyCustomAdapter adapter= new MyCustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mySpinner);
spi.setAdapter(adapter);
}

Comment: @JigarShekh post the full stack my running the app again. no snap shots pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this line before using ,

```
ArrayList<CustomSpinnerRow_Info> spinnerInfo= new ArrayList<CustomSpinnerRow_Info>();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like the following : \

```
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, null, false);
```

and please give me some feedback .

Hope that helps .

Comment: what difference would this make. getLayoutInfalter will work http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater() if adapter is a inner class of activity

Comment: @Amrola Sorry your suggestion does't work. My program still not working.

Comment: @Amrola View view=convertView;